# For what reltively prime integers $a$ and $b$ does the expression $2ab$ an even numeric palindrome?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I currently doing some research on numeric palindromes. And I am stack with the problem:

For what reltively prime integers $a$ and $b$ does the expression $2ab$  an even numeric palindrome?

Since one solution is the pair (2,11), is there a general form for its solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you conjecture is not true since (2,11)=1 and 2∗2∗11=44

Comment: Oh I see, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand—which requirement is not met?

Comment: The question of mine has been edited